# Contract is working but no "Verify and Publish"

Tags: contract-debugging, verify

Contract is working but no "Read Contract" and "Write Contract" and no "Code"

And no verify and publish.

So i tried coding and the Minted Tokens are correct, 100% of the holders is on the Dev wallet, but there is nothing to Verify, Publish, No Read Contract, No Write Contract.

BUT, i tried adding liquidity but the contract is working as intended but i think that there is something that i missed, but i dont know what.

Comment: Can you point to it on Etherscan? Do you have the code somewhere? What was the compiler version, the target EVM and was there compile-time optimisation?

Answer (score 0):

So i compiled and deployed it again, and there was some issue in the minting part.

it minted the tokens with the decimals(18)

Comment: Sorry, I misread your answer. I understand that you solved the problem by recompiling and deploying again?